# float of list item pairs does not work in < IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, css-float, html-lists

I have something like this:

```
<ul>
<li class="first">Hello</li>
<li class="second">World</li>
<li class="first">Hello</li>
<li class="second">World</li>
</ul>​
```

And CSS like this:

```
.first {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}

.second {
    float: left;
    clear: right;
}
```

I would like to have it like this:

HelloWorld
HelloWorld

But in IE7 it shows up like this:
HelloWorldWorld
Hello

Can anyone explain me why, and how to solve this?

​Here is a link to

[JSFiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/pQApA/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The issue happens because the parent element (in this case the `ul`) has no width, so the elements are collapsing badly. By adding width to the children and the parent, you can achieve the result you are looking for.

Here is an updated version of your JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vVwQM/